# How can I find span from code behind and add user control to it?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I've a div

```
<div id="PageContent" runat="server"></div>
```

Now I'm adding HTML to it from code behind(c#) like this

```
PageContent.InnerHtml =mytext;
```

where `mytext` is the content I want to add in `PageContent` div, mytext contains a span in between some text(it can be any string), something like this

```
This is some <span id="span1"> </span> text
```

How can I find span from code behind and add user control to it?

Answer (score 4):

```
//This is some <span id="span1" runat="server"> </span>

//In the code behind...

var span1 = this.FindControl("span1") as HtmlGenericControl;
var controlPath = "path of your user control";
var someControl = LoadControl(controlPath);
span1.Controls.Add(someControl);
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Parse / extract `span1` from your `mytext`, create `HtmlGenericControl` with this parsed information, add it to `PageContent` div then try adding user control to this `span`.

Comment: But the point is he is creating that span on runtime. Doing so will also not give

Comment: You are right @AnirudhAgarwal..

Coder i already tried that,it dosen't work.

Comment: well @coder what you answered is the whole process that should be done,it would be really good if you can tell me how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
 span.InnerHtml = "Hello ";
 span.Attributes["id"] = "span";
 span.ID = "span";
 String myTesxt = @"This is some " + span.InnerHtml + " text";
 myDiv.InnerHtml = myTesxt;
 span.InnerHtml = "";

 myDiv.Controls.Add(span);
 var a=myDiv.FindControl("span");
```

Try adding span like this in your Div then you will find it in your code behind.
 Try this. Hopefully this will solve your purpose.

You can add attributes in the span according to your need.

Comment: you don't need  

`span.InnerHtml = "";` and

`span.Attributes["id"] = "span";`

It works fine without it also,so made the necessary changes.

Comment: when i add a User Control after adding a span as you said, It gets added to my page after **text** and when you look at the HTML span gets added after _This is some Hello text_.

Answer (score 0):

To add pure tag of the span with the back code please as following code

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script>");            
    sb.Append("alert('aa')");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
    span.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
    this.form1.Controls.Add(span);
```